# Accessing Spark RDDs from a web browser via thrift server - java

Tags: apache-spark, thrift, rdd

We have processed our data using `Spark 1.2.1` with Java and stored in Hive tables. We want to access this data as RDDs from an web browser.

I read documentation and I understood the steps to do the task.

I am unable to find the way to interact with `Spark SQL RDDs` via thrift server. Examples I found have belw line in the code and I am not find the class for this in Spark 1.2.1 java API docs.

`HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext`

In github i saw scala examples using 
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver , but I dont see this in Java API docs. Not sure if I am missing something.

Did anybody had luck with accessing Spark SQL RDDs from a browser via thrift? Can you post the code snippet. We are using Java.

Answer (score 1):

I've got most of this working. Lets dissect each part of it: (References at bottom of post)

`HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext` is defined in Scala. I was never able to access it from Java or from Python using Py4j, and am no JVM expert, but I ended up switching to Scala. This may have something to do with the annotation `@DeveloperApi` . This is how I imported it Scala in Spark 1.6.1:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2
```

For anyone reading this and not using Hive, a Spark SQL context won't do, and you need a hive context. However, the HiveContext constructor requires a Java spark context, not a scala one.

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

var hiveContext = new HiveContext(JavaSparkContext.toSparkContext(sc))
```

Now start the thrift server

```
HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext(hiveContext)

// Yay
```

Next, we need to make our RDDs available as SQL tables. First, we have to convert them into Spark SQL DataFrames:

```
val someDF = hiveContext.createDataFrame(someRDD)
```

Then, we need to turn them into Spark SQL tables. You do this by persisting them to Hive, or making the RDD available as a temporary table.

Persist to Hive:

```
// Deprecated since Spark 1.4, to be removed in Spark 2.0:
someDF.saveAsTable("someTable")

// Up-to-date at time of writing
someDF.write().saveAsTable("someTable")
```

Or, use a temporary table:

```
// Use the Data Frame as a Temporary Table
// Introduced in Spark 1.3.0
someDF.registerTempTable("someTable")
```

Note - temporary tables are isolated to an SQL session.
Spark's hive thrift server is multi-session by default
in version 1.6 (one session per connection). Therefore,
for clients to access temporary tables you've registered,
you'll need to set the option `spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession` to `true`

You can test this by querying the tables in `beeline`, a command line utility for interacting with the hive thrift server. It ships with Spark.

Finally, you need a way of accessing the hive thrift server from the browser. Thanks to its awesome developers, it has an HTTP mode, so if you want to build a web app, you can use the thrift protocol over AJAX requests from the browser. A simpler strategy might be to create an IPython notebook, and use `pyhive` to connect to the thrift server.

Data Frame Reference:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html

singleSession option pull request:
https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-commits/201511.mbox/%3Cc2bd1313f7ca4e618ec89badbd8f9f31@git.apache.org%3E

HTTP mode and beeline howto:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#distributed-sql-engine

Pyhive:
https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive

HiveThriftServer2 startWithContext definition:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6b1a6180e7bd45b0a0ec47de9f7c7956543f4dfa/sql/hive-thriftserver/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/thriftserver/HiveThriftServer2.scala#L56-73

Answer (score 0):

Thrift is JDBC/ODBC server.
You can connect to it via JDBC/ODBC connections and access content through the  HiveDriver.
You can **not** get RDDs back from it, because `HiveContext` is not available.
What you refered to is an experimental feature not available for Java.

As a workaround, you could re-parse the results and create your structures for your client.
For example:

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
private static String hiveConnectionString = "jdbc:hive2://YourHiveServer:Port";
private static String tableName = "SOME_TABLE";

Class c = Class.forName(driverName);
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(hiveConnectionString, "user", "pwd");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql = "select * from "+tableName;
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
parseResultsToObjects(res);
```